# How handle empty term/token after applying filter-solr

Tags: solr

In my case I need to apply `KeepWordFilterFactory` filter to get only colour name:

```
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory"/>      
<filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory" words="colorwordset.txt"/>       
</analyzer>
```

When my query is (red shirt) above works fine but when my query is(shirt) then empty token created and result count become zero.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You ask Solr to delete everything but color words. Why do you wonder why a query without a color word turns empty?

Comment: let`s say another example suppose i have applied 'stopfilterfactory'  on query "at the" then how empty query will be handle.